# PHP 5.4 upgrade NOTICE: Array to string conversion in textbox.inc.php in like 32

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have searched through many of these types of notices but my problem is still not answered.  I am not very saavy with php but am focused on learning more.  I have only worked with this code for 1 year now.  If someone could look over these 12 lines of code and tell me if my problem exists in here, it would be appreciated.  Also, if this is the reason my Mysql database won't be written to since upgrading from 5.2 to 5.4.  Thank you.

```
<?php

23  function textbox ($label,$name,$size,$isreq=0,$value="")
24  {
25  print ("$label");
26  if ($label != "")
27    print (":");
28  if ($isreq != 0)
29    print ("<FONT COLOR='$990000'>*</FONT>");
30  print (" <INPUT TYPE='text' NAME='$name' SIZE='$size'");
31  if ($value != "")
32    print ("VALUE=$value");
33    print (">\n");
34  }
35  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's only notice, which means you passed array which was converted to string.

in line 32, $value is array, but it must be string.

Comment: I don't completely understand.  How did this code work in 5.2 but it will not work in 5.4?

Comment: PHP 5.4 is strict about this, as line 32 is trying to print string, but variabale is an array. Hence the "Array to string conversion" notice.